# A paper by Elashvili (translation request)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, soft-question, translation

I would like to know if there is an English version of a paper by Elashvili called "Centralizers of nilpotent elements in semisimple Lie algebras".

If not, is there atleast an online version of the original paper that can be accessed (preferably freely) ?

[added] Here is a more elaborate reference to the paper, which I suspect has appeared in a publication/collection with multiple names :

A. G Elashvili, *Centralizers of nilpotent elements in semi-simple Lie algebras*, Sakarth. SSR Mecn. Akad. Math. Inst. Srom (= Akad. Nauk Gruzin. SSR Trusy Tbiliss. Mat Inst. Ramazde = Publ. Math. Inst. Tbilisi) **46** (1975), pgs 109-132.

Comment: That paper was in a collection published in the mid-1970s and may be hard to track down.  However, he has continued to be fairly active, so it's worth contacting him directly.   I've met him and had some email correspondence.   At the time Alexander Elashvili had the address in Georgia:  alela@rmi.acnet.ge   (see also a recent joint paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1205.0515).

Comment: Thanks, I will surely drop him an email. I have also added a more elaborate reference in case that helps someone track it down.

Comment: P.S.  Probably the more recent literature covers the ground thoroughly.   In particular, the determintion of component groups of centralizers was improved in a 2003 J. Algebra paper by McNinch and Sommers, while the 1985 book by R.W. Carter has a comprehensive treatment of the older work from the Bala-Carter viewpoint (including many tables).  Collkingwood-McGovern covered most aspects of the classification in their book on nilpotent orbits.

Comment: Carter does give a through discussion of topics like the Springer-Steinberg dimension formula following his discussion of the Bala-Carter theorem. When compiling tables, he refers to the work of Elashvili (for exceptional cases) for "information about the centralizers". It really isn't clear to me what method Elashvili would have used to get at that information. There is also a paper of Elkington along similar lines but his tables and the ones in Carter's book don't match and Carter does not cite Elkington. It seemed like a clearer picture would emerge if I could look at Elashvili's paper.

Comment: Elashvili's email is now alela@rmi.ge, or aelashvili@gmail.com. I've asked him about it, if you contact him he said he will try to get you scans of the paper. There is no English version though

Comment: @Aswin: Elkington was a Warwick student, but his published work had some errors.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for the contact information! I have sent a request.

Comment: @ Jim Thanks for clarifying. I recognize table errors are somewhat hard to avoid in this corner of representation theory. On a side note, I think it was Elkington's work that was first to point out errors in Dynkin's 'weighted Dynkin diagrams' for nilpotent orbits in the exceptional cases.